# Qual a importância de usar ON DELETE CASCADE e ON UPDATE CASCADE em uma tabela com chave(s) estrangeira(s)?

Tags: mysql

Eu queria saber o porquê é importante usar `ON DELETE CASCADE` e `ON UPDATE CASCADE` em uma tabela com chave(s) estrangeira(s), principalmente quando se há trigger nela(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A importância de se utilizar o CASCADE é para garantir a integridade referencial do banco de dados, o que garante que um registro (pai) que tenha um dado referenciado por outro registro (filho), ao ser atualizado (deletado ou modificado) reflita isto no registro que o tenha como referência, assim como permite que o filho não tenha um dado corrompido no seu registro (referência inexistente).

Portanto, no ON DELETE CASCADE (se for realmente necessário), todas as tuplas em tabelas que tenham como FK o ID da tupla deletada, será deletada, garantindo que não haverá tuplas sem FK. Já no ON UPDATE CASCADE, os dados da tabela ao ser atualizados, caso sejam referenciados em outra tabela ou na mesma, serão atualizados em cascata.

Em resumo, é para garantir a "INTEGRIDADE REFERENCIAL DE BANCO DE DADOS".